# How to link a Nuxt app to an API server in docker-compose

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I have two containers in my `docker-compose.yml`: `frontend` and `server`.
The frontend communicates to the API of the server via Apollo and uses `process.env.VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP` to get the http endpoint.

In the `docker-compose.yml` I have:

```
environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP: 'http://server:4000/graphql'
      VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_WS: 'ws://server:4000/graphql'
```

Which works perfectly fine for server side rendering with NuxtJS. On the client side although I am getting an error:

```
OPTIONS http://server:4000/graphql net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

If I set `VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'` in `docker-compose.yml` it works on client side but not with server side rendering. I am getting `ECONNREFUSED` error then.

So the question is: how can I resolve the path to my API on server and client side with NuxtJS?

My complete `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: node
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: npm run docker
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP: 'http://server:4000/graphql'
      VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_WS: 'ws://server:4000/graphql'
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - app

  server:
    container_name: server
    image: node
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: npm run docker
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      PORT: 4000
      DATABASE_URL: mongodb://database:27017
    networks:
      - app

  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
```

Comment: You should not have to declare HOST: 0.0.0.0 in your compose file. Can you paste your compose file? Otherwise it is difficult to debug the issue. Also avoid using "localhost" when working with containers. It leads to issues most of the times.

Comment: I added my complete docker-compose file. I thought I need HOST 0.0.0.0 to use nuxt with docker.

Comment: Can you please do one thing: add a line in your /etc/hosts like this: "127.0.0.1    server" and try again. If you are on Windows the location of the hosts file is different

Comment: Then my requests don't work on client and server side :D also without the host entry I cannot reach the nuxt app at all.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way but I solved it with special rules for server and frontend.

Load js file in apollo config  `nuxt.config.js`

```
    clientConfigs: {
      default: '~/plugins/apollo.js',
    },
```

plugins/apollo.js:

```
export default function(context) {
  let httpEndpoint = process.env.APOLLO_SERVER_HTTP || 'http://localhost:4000/graphql';
  let wsEndpoint = process.env.APOLLO_SERVER_WS || 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql';

  if (process.client) {
    httpEndpoint = process.env.APOLLO_CLIENT_HTTP || 'http://localhost:4000/graphql';
    wsEndpoint = process.env.APOLLO_CLIENT_WS || 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql';
  }

  return {
    httpEndpoint,
    httpLinkOptions: {
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    },
    wsEndpoint,
  };
}
```

pass variables via docker-compose:

```
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      APOLLO_SERVER_HTTP: 'http://server:4000/graphql'
      APOLLO_CLIENT_HTTP: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
      APOLLO_SERVER_WS: 'ws://server:4000/graphql'
      APOLLO_CLIENT_WS: 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql'
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm too bad there hasn't been a better answer to this yet. You could definitely work around when testing as suggested by creating an entry in /etc/hosts to the api service as named in docker, but that would not really be ideal for ci/cd :-(